# If possible how do I single out a app from starting in Safe Mode

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, active-directory, safe-mode, gesture

If possible how do I single out a app from starting in Safe Mode. I want to use Safe Mode with out Photos involved for example. Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you think Safe Mode loads any apps.

Comment: Im going to go look at it again

Comment: Now I can't get it start in Safe Mode.

Comment: try Verbose mode...hold the Command (⌘) – V key